# How to get the desired outpout from the following list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

Suppose the is a list with following values

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

The Required Output is

print

```
1
1+2
1+2+3
1+2+3+4
1+2+3+4+5
1+2+3+4+5+6
1+2+3+4+5+6+7
```

Please help me to get the above answer..

Comment: Sounds like a computer science assignment… I guess `for` loop**s** are the key…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there can be many approaches to get the answer, you can use following code to get your answer.

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
temp = A[0]
print(temp)
for x in range(1, len(A)):

    for y in range(x):
        temp = str(temp) + "+" + str(A[y+1])
    print(temp)
    temp = A[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

We use a for loop to iterate over the array, and concatenate each consecutive element along with a `+`.
In the first iteration we start with only the first element in the array
In the `i'th` iteration, we concatenate all the elements until `i`

Here's a piece of code that does that:

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

for i in range(len(A)):
    s = str(A[0])
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        s += "+" + str(A[j])
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for i in range(len(a)+1):
    for j in range(i):
        if(j+1==i):
            print(a[j],end='')
        else:
            print(a[j],'+ ',end='')
    print(('\r'))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it